# Symfony/Assetic: Cannot use Compass in dev mode

Tags: symfony, assetic, compass

I'm desperate. I can generate CSS from the Sass with the help of `bin/console assetic:dump` command just fine, and it works in production. However if I will try to run this through controller - it falls apart.

So, for example this: `http://zmasakrowani-symfony.localhost/app_dev.php/css/b82eb50_main_1.css`

Gives me this error:

```
/* [exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | Assetic\Exception\FilterException [message] An error occurred while running: '/usr/sbin/ruby' '/home/luken/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/compass' 'compile' '/home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/var/cache/dev' '--boring' '--config' '/home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/var/cache/dev/assetic_compassXyzU4Z' '--sass-dir' '' '--css-dir' '' '/home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/var/cache/dev/assetic_compasse7YLuO.scss'

Error Output: /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'compass' (>= 0.a) among 12 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError) Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/tmp/.gem/ruby/2.3.0:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0', execute `gem env` for more information    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'    from /home/luken/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/compass:22:in `<main>'


Input: @import "compass";


.articles {   height: 20px;   background: yellow;   color: red; } [1] Assetic\Exception\FilterException: An error occurred while running: '/usr/sbin/ruby' '/home/luken/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/compass' 'compile' '/home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/var/cache/dev' '--boring' '--config' '/home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/var/cache/dev/assetic_compassXyzU4Z' '--sass-dir' '' '--css-dir' '' '/home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/var/cache/dev/assetic_compasse7YLuO.scss'

Error Output: /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'compass' (>= 0.a) among 12 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError) Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/tmp/.gem/ruby/2.3.0:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0', execute `gem env` for more information    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'    from /home/luken/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/compass:22:in `<main>'


Input: @import "compass";


.articles {   height: 20px;   background: yellow;   color: red; }
    at n/a
        in /home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Exception/FilterException.php line 40

    at Assetic\Exception\FilterException::fromProcess(object(Process))
        in /home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/CompassFilter.php line 356

    at Assetic\Filter\CompassFilter->filterLoad(object(FileAsset))
        in /home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/FilterCollection.php line 62

    at Assetic\Filter\FilterCollection->filterLoad(object(FileAsset))
        in /home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/BaseAsset.php line 94

    at Assetic\Asset\BaseAsset->doLoad('@import &quot;compass&quot;;


.articles {   height: 20px;   background: yellow;   color: red; }', null)
        in /home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/FileAsset.php line 65

    at Assetic\Asset\FileAsset->load()
        in /home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/BaseAsset.php line 103

    at Assetic\Asset\BaseAsset->dump(object(AssetCacheKeyFilter))
        in /home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/AssetCache.php line 69

    at Assetic\Asset\AssetCache->dump(object(AssetCacheKeyFilter))
        in /home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/Controller/AsseticController.php line 90

    at Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Controller\AsseticController->render(object(Request), 'b82eb50', '0')
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(AsseticController), 'render'), array(object(Request), 'b82eb50', '0'))
        in /home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 139

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in /home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 62

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php line 169

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in /home/luken/srv/http/projects/2016/zmasakrowani-symfony/web/app_dev.php line 30


*/
```

The main problem is with this:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in `to_specs': Could not find 'compass'
```

However I have Compass for sure. It works with bin/console assetic:dump , why it doesn't work only in dev environment/assetic controller?

Some more data. My assetic configuration:

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    bundles: [AppBundle]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        compass:
            bin: '/home/luken/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/compass'
```

And in my Twig template, in header I have this:

```
    {% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite,compass'
        "@AppBundle/Resources/sass/main.scss"
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

**Added #1:**

Also output of the `gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0 (2015-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/luken/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/luken/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
     - /home/luken/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--user-install"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/luken/bin
     - /home/luken/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin
     - /home/luken/.composer/vendor/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin
     - /usr/bin/site_perl
     - /usr/bin/vendor_perl
     - /usr/bin/core_perl
```

**Added #2:**

One more notable thing: Apache process is owned by my user.

Comment: hey man... I'm having the same problem here. Did you fix this? Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately not, didn't have time at the time. I will be revisiting it in a few weeks probably and will post if I will find an answer, but I have nothing right now. :(